# Building with Ant in Eclipse - javac not recognizing lambda expression (Java 1.8)

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, version

I am trying to build an existing project using Ant in Eclipse.  The problem is that `javac` does not recognize the use of a Lambda expression (`error: illegal start of expression`) in one of the files, and the build fails during the `compile` phase of the Ant.

Within Eclipse, I've ensured that the `Java Compiler` compliance level is set to 1.8 and that Java 8 is in the `Java Build Path`.

I've also ensured that the my `Path`, `JAVA_HOME`, and `JRE_HOME` all point to my Java 8 directory (in `Path` it points to the `/bin` directory).

For giggles, the compile section of my `build.xml` file is:

```
<target name="compile" depends="setup">
    <javac destdir="${base}/${build.dir}"
           srcdir="${base}/${src.dir}"
           deprecation="true"
           verbose="false"
           includeantruntime="false">
           <classpath refid="libs" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

I'm not really sure what to do next.  I've resorted to restarting Eclipse hoping for magic to happen.  Any suggestions or help are welcome!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using ?

Comment: When you run Ant under Eclipse it uses whatever is configured in your Ant installation.  You must properly configure Ant to use Java 8 as well.

Comment: use `<echo>Java version: ${ant.java.version}</echo>` to check which version you are actually using when running ant

Comment: The Ant 'javac' task does not know anything about things like compliance levels that you have set in Eclipse. You need to specify those are attributes of the 'javac' task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `<echo> Java version: ${ant.java.version}</echo>` to my `build.xml` revealed that Ant was still running Java 1.7.

I added the directory location of my Java 8 `javac` and modified the `javac` task with the `executable` and `fork` attributes to use it:

```
<property name="javac1.8" location="/path/to/java8/bin/javac" />
<target name="compile" depends="setup">
    <javac executable="{$javac1.8}" fork="yes"
           destdir="${base}/${build.dir}"
           srcdir="${base}/${src.dir}"
           deprecation="true"
           verbose="false"
           includeantruntime="false">
           <classpath refid="libs" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

Thanks so much for the comments @Jim Garrison, @wero, and @greg-449.  Your powers combined lead me to my answer.